# Is it possible to access the specific folder of user for our app in flutter? Like status save

Tags: flutter

I had applied for relase a app on play store of status saver app. They had raised a query on asking a permission of user phone access storage. Give me the solution how i will relase my app?

I want solution of my query for relase a app in flutter with access of hidden .statuses folder

Answer (score 0):

You can access a user's storage using the `permission_handler` package.

Accessing specific hidden folders like `.statuses` might not be possible on all devices and platforms due to security and privacy considerations (ig).

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I had already use the permission handler  but what is the solution of that access of that .statuses folder